# Adding schemas to my Xml document takes long time to complete

Tags: .net, xml, initialization

I have a program that I use to edit xmls.

I start with adding base schemas to my Xml like this

```
    Sub Initialize()
        document.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#",
                             ".\XSD\xmlsig.xsd")
        ' Dummy data here
        document.Schemas.Add("http://needed.url.org/docs/xsd/v1.2/", 
                             ".\XSD\myxsd_v1.2.xsd")
        initialized = True
    End Sub
```

Tho problem is that the second schema addition takes long time to complete, over 60 seconds vs the 13ms of the first one.

I already noticed:

- the second link points to a not found page but I'm not sure that's the issue.
- Trying to add a XmlUrlResolver myself and fiddle with the properties made no difference.
- Disabling my network adapter made the operation instantaneous so I'm guessing that network is a factor and xsd validation is not but I can be wrong.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I speed up this piece of code? Cause waiting for 70+ seconds for the application to initialize the document is not really ideal.

Edit 1: Analizing network packets I found out that a GET request for the xmldsig-core-schema.xsd it's fired but if I try to add the schema locally I get an exception about DTD not allowed in my document, no idea on how I can work around this though

Edit 2: Modified the xsd that requests the above mentioned schema, now the program correctly load the local version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C deliberately delays responses to requests for commonly-used schemas and DTDs in order to encourage users to access a local copy in preference; they started doing this a few years ago because they couldn't handle the thousands of requests coming in per second.

Do some network monitoring to see which resources are being requested (it may not be the ones that are directly named in your application, but others that are referenced indirectly); and then make sure your XmlResolver responds to these requests using local copies.

Comment: I tried to look into this and I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Looks like you now have a new problem and therefore you should accept this answer and raise a new question.